# Existence of solutions for inhomogeneous Helmholtz Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Lets say I have a bounded domain $\Omega$ in 2D. If I consider the inhomogeneous Helmholtz equation with Dirichlet Boundary conditions along the Boundary $\delta\Omega$:

$u_{xx}(x,y) + u_{yy}(x,y) + \eta^2(x,y) u(x,y) = g(x,y)$ on $\Omega$

$u = f$, on $\delta\Omega$

What can I say about the existence of solutions in function of $\eta(x,y)$? Note that my $\eta$ is not necessarily constant, but at least always positive.

Regularity requirements are no issue for me. If everything needs to be smooth, that's fine. If the above problem does not have a solution, which restrictions do I need to consider to get a solution?

I'm also thankful for references to Textbooks/Papers that state the existence of solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Melenk's PhD Thesis: On Generalized Finite Element Methods

You can download it here:
http://www.asc.tuwien.ac.at/~melenk/publications/publications.html

In section 8.1 he discusses existence and uniqueness for the Helmholtz equation. Maybe recall [Fredholm's Theorems](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fredholm_theorems) before hand.

Comment: Your answer seems to be alright. I also found a good discussion in the following two Books: _Em, A. & Guermond, J.-L. Theory and Practice of Finite Elements_ as well as in _Dret, H. L. & Lucquin, B. Partial Differential Equations: Modeling, Analysis and Numerical Approximation_